# How to insert abbreviate hashtag-starting lines in Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim, abbreviation

I have the following line in my `ftplugin/cpp.vim` folder:

```
inorea <buffer> #def #define
```

And it keeps on popping errors whenever I enter Neovim. The entire code goes like this:

```
if (&ft != 'cpp')
    finish
endif

inorea <buffer> #inc<lt> #include <lt>><left>
inorea <buffer> #inc #include ""<left>
inorea <buffer> #def #define
nnoremap <buffer> #inc<lt> i#include <lt>><left>
nnoremap <buffer> #inc" i#include ""<left>
nnoremap <buffer> #def<Space> i#define 
inoremap <buffer> /* /**/<left><left>

" For Single-File Codes : Save, Compile, and Run
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<CR>:!g++ % -o %<.exe<CR><CR>:!%<.exe<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <C-F5> :w<CR>:!g++ % -o %<.exe<CR><CR>:tabe<CR>:terminal<CR>3j$a
```

Funnily enough, line 5 doesn't pop an error, and they do work in `.cpp` files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abbreviations work depends on the `'iskeyword'` option. See `:h Abbreviations`.

The left-hand side of the abbreviation can either be only keyword characters (*full-id*), non-keyword characters ending with a keyword character (*end-id*), or any characters ending with a non-keyword-characters (*non-id*).

If the `#` character is *not* part of `'iskeyword'`, then `#def` is none of the three types and thus `:ab #def ...` is invalid. Because that's keyword characters starting with a non-keyword character.

The format of `'iskeyword'` is rather cryptic (see `:h 'isfname'`), but by default it's set to `@,48-57,_,192-255`. It doesn't include `#`.

Quick test:

```
:set isk=a-z
:ab #def foo
E474: Invalid argument
:set isk=a-z,#
:ab #def foo
```

So, you could put `set iskeyword+=#` before your abbreviations, but that might lead to other issues as well, since the characters from `'iskeyword'` are used for a lot of things.